# Make Index.php?page=loripsum to /#/loripsum

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I would like to change

`http://www.loremipsum.com/index.php?page=loripsum`

to

`http://www.loremipsum.com/#/loripsum`.

Is that somehow possible with mod-rewite?

Comment: FYI http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2011/02/09/Hash-Blecch

Answer (score 1):

No.

http://www.loremipsum.com/loripsum would be possible, but the part after the # ([fragment id](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)) will not even be sent to the server. There is no way for Apache or any other web server to read this part of the URL with a regular browser.

That pattern you describe uses client-side JavaScript to get the corresponding resources and display them.